# How to set csrf token cookie when a view return a json data?

Tags: ajax, django, django-csrf

Here is my signup view, and I use ajax to post.
I have followed the official document. If the csrftoken cookie exists, it works fine.

However, the view returning json data didn't set the csrftoken. How to deal with this?

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = UserCreationForm(postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = postdata.get('username', '')
            password = postdata.get('password1', '')
            from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
            new_user = authenticate(username=user, password=password)
            if new_user and new_user.is_active:
                login(request, new_user)
                data = json.dumps({'success': 'true'})
                return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
            else:
                data = json.dumps({'username': '该用户处于非正常状态'})
                return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            error_list = {}
            for ek in form.errors:
                error_list[ek] = form.errors[ek][0]
            data = json.dumps(error_list)
            return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `X-CSRFToken` header in your ajax call, refer to the offical docs on csrf with ajax for details.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: but the csrf toekn cookie must exists

Comment: I just want to know how the csrf token cookie is set